# What is the difference between handlers render_post and render_complete?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

what is the difference between `bpy.app.handlers.render_post` and `bpy.app.handlers.render_complete`?

Comment: Related: [Script to add dummy handler to each render handler] each prints the name of handler to console  to indicate when invoked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`render_post`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_post) runs after each frame is rendered. If you have 10 frames, this event will fire 10 times.

[`render_complete`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_complete) runs only once, after all frames were rendered (when the entire animation's rendering process is complete).